# Redshift copy latest csv file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a S3 bucket stores daily log files, named "Log_YYYY_MM_DD". 
Also, I have a table in Redshift only stores data of the latest log.
For example:

- In S3, I have "Log_Date0.csv", "Log_Date1.csv", "Log_Date2.csv"
- And the redshift table should only contains data in "Log_Date2.csv"

How can I setup a daily data pipeline so that redshift automatically copy the latest log contains and rewrite the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift cannot "automatically copy" files. It will only load files when the SQL `COPY` command is issued.

Therefore, it is up to you to create the necessary commands to `TRUNCATE` the table and then `COPY` the data from Amazon S3.

You could write a `cron` job that uses `psql` v8.0.2 (to match Redshift) to run the SQL commands. Alternatively, you could use a third-party ETL product that can load the data for you.

To trigger the automatic load of information into Amazon Redshift when a new file is added to an Amazon S3 bucket, you could:

- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that sends the `COPY` command to Redshift via a psql/JDBC connection
- Configure the S3 bucket to trigger the Lambda function when `ObjectCreated`

See: [A Zero-Administration Amazon Redshift Database Loader](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/a-zero-administration-amazon-redshift-database-loader/)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the comment. The question to me is, how to ask Redshift to "copy data" from the latest file in the S3 bucket.

Comment: Or, I mean whenever there's a new file added into S3 bucket, how to trigger something to add the content into redshift.

Comment: Thanks John, I managed to get this to work using manifest file.

Comment: @DarrenWu
I am facing the same problem. How does your manifest file look like? Does it allow regex pattern matching? From the example in the docs, you have to provide the exact path of the s3 object

Comment: @Alan Please create a new question rather than adding a comment on a one year-old answer.

Comment: Hi Alan, I ended up having a python code which connects to S3 and get the latest file name, and then save the file name to a manifest file and re-upload to S3. For copying content to table, only use the manifest file. Not a clean way to do, but solve the problem